# What is HorizonRequestError error 11?

Tags: horizon, error

Horizon returns errors with numbers, but as far as I can see, there aren't numbers in the error reference.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (stellarsdk.HorizonRequestError error 11.)
```

What is error 11?

More importantly, how do you make heads or tails of these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11 is an internal error: `An unknown error occured.`

You can find a list at:
https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#possible-errors